# Set foreign key of table1 on part of consist primary key of table2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Firstly sorry for my English)

I have following tables:

1) **rejection_reasons**

- rejection_reason_id
- locale_code
- title

*Primary key:* rejection_reason_id, locale_code

2) **order_rejection_reasons**

- order_id
- rejection_reason_id

*Primary key:* order_id

*Foreign key:* rejection_reason_id (**Note!** without field *locale_code*)

---

Entities:

```
class RejectionReason
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="rejection_reason_id", type="smallint", length=1, nullable=false)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="locale_code", type="string", length=2, nullable=false, options={"fixed"=true})
     */
    private $localeCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderRejectionReason", mappedBy="rejectionReason", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $orderRejectionReasons;

    /**
     * @param int    $id
     * @param string $localeCode
     */
    public function __construct($id, $localeCode)
    {
        $this->id                    = $id;
        $this->localeCode            = $localeCode;
        $this->orderRejectionReasons = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

---

```
class OrderRejectionReason
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var RejectionReason
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RejectionReason", inversedBy="orderRejectionReasons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rejection_reason_id", referencedColumnName="rejection_reason_id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * })
     */
    private $rejectionReason;
}
```

Doctrine returns error:

**The join columns of the association 'rejectionReason' have to match to ALL identifier columns of the target entity 'App\Entity\RejectionReason', however 'locale_code' are missing.**

Could you help me set relation between these tables?

Answer (score 2):

The join columns of the association 'rejectionReason' have to match to **ALL identifier columns**, so you should take a look at the identifier columns. As you can see localcode is marked as an id (@ORM\Id) aswell as id, this means that you created a composite primary key.

Take a look at: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Because it is a composite primary key you cannot relate to only one of the two identifiers (JoinColumn,  referencedColumnName="id").

You may consider making localeCode unique instead of an id which should solve you problem.(so you have to decide if localCode should be an id) You could also try to add localCode to the JoinColumn annotation.

Comment: Making `localeCode` unique is quite different, so it might not solve the problem. But I would advise as well to not use a composite primary key. I had some problems with it in the past and it seems not as well supported by doctrine. Having a dedicated ID is cheap and easy. If you still want to do it, I can provide an example if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the extra curly braces and `JoinColumn` statement

```
class OrderRejectionReason
{
    /**
     * @var RejectionReason
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RejectionReason", inversedBy="orderRejectionReasons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rejection_reason_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $rejectionReason;
}
```

EDIT I:
Added `name="rejection_reason_id", referencedColumnName="rejection_reason_id"`

EDIT II:
Changed `referencedColumnName="rejection_reason_id"` to `referencedColumnName="id"`

Comment: **New error:** The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\RejectionReason'. **+ Old error:** The join columns of the association 'rejectionReason' have to match to ALL identifier columns of the target entity 'App\Entity\RejectionReason', however 'locale_code' are missing.

Comment: In case:
`code`
/**
     * @var RejectionReason
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RejectionReason", inversedBy="orderRejectionReasons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rejection_reason_id", referencedColumnName="rejection_reason_id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $rejectionReason;
`code`
doctrine returns only **Old error**

Comment: Ok I updated my answer. Try to add `name="rejection_reason_id", referencedColumnName="rejection_reason_id"` it seems they are required for your situation

Comment: **Old error:** The join columns of the association 'rejectionReason' have to match to ALL identifier columns of the target entity 'App\Entity\RejectionReason', however 'locale_code' are missing.

Comment: Try to change `referencedColumnName="id"` maybe it has to be the variable name and not the table name

Comment: **New error:** The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Entity\RejectionReason'. **+ Old error**

Comment: Hmm I guess that doctrine has an problem with your name for the id column. In normal symfony / doctrine projects the id isn't prefixed with the table name like you did. You could try to change this and hopefully it's then working. Give it a try and let me know if that works. (`order_id` => `id` and `rejection_reason_id` => `id`)